# Issues importing to_dlpack from TensorFlow for NVIDIA Merlin

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently trying to build a recommender system for a project using NVIDIA Merlin with Python. As of now I have been trying to install the packages and import them into a python file on my Macbook but when I attempt to run `import merlin.models.tf as mm`, I receive the error ImportError: cannot import name 'to_dlpack' from 'tensorflow.python'. After looking over the Tensorflow documentation it seems like this might be an issue with the decorator on the to_dlpack function in tensorflow/python/dlpack/dlpack.py which states that to_dlpack is coming from experimental. How should I go about fixing this? Should I change the decorator locally?

Instead of messing with the local installation of Tensorflow I have instead tried to import the to_dlpack function by calling `from tensorflow.python.dlpack.dlpack import to_dlpack` which has returned the actual function. But would prefer to understand a more in-depth fix.